# Pyspark partitionBy function not re-partitioning data-frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm re-partitioning DataFrame with below function , but when I view number of partition on DataFrame it is not showing the updated one, but the initial one.

```
df.rdd.repartition(100)
df.rdd.partitionBy(100,partitionFunc="HashPartitioner")
df.rdd.getNumPartitions() // Result - 519
```

It is supposed to show number of partition as 100 , but instead it's giving 519 (initial value). Am I missing anything ( Running the code in pyspark shell. )

Comment: df.rdd.repartition(100) and just gone. It is not saved anywhere, right?

Comment: yes ! Oh I will have to create new DF as data-frames are immutable , right?

Comment: data-frames are immutable ? yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save your repartitioned dataframe some value or new dataframe and check it again.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'test')], ['id', 'value'])
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
# 1

df = df.repartition(10)
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
# 10
```

Comment: ThankYou !  Also , ```df.rdd.partitionBy(100,partitionFunc="HashPartitioner")``` will result into an RDD , so will I have to convert it back to DataFrame , or there is another function that can perform task directly on DataFrame. So I do not need to convert it back to DataFrame.

Comment: That's up to you.

Comment: Is there any better approach or we will have to convert it to RDD and then back to DataFrame to apply HashPartitioner.

Comment: I know the later one only.